# Elasticsearch query to return those documents also which are missing an indexed value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I am trying to form a query for my node js application. Basically it would be a keyword query from the client and I have this requirement to return those documents also in Elasticsearch even if any field is missing along with all the other normal documents which are expected to get returned. I tried something like this in kibana

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {"exists": {"field": "xyz"}}
      ]
    }
  }  
}
```

But this is only returning the documents missing this particular field and not all the documents. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Is this the full query because it does not contain the keyword query you are talking about in the question? Also, you are using a must_not which means that elasticsearch must not return all documents where this field exists, equivalent to, elasticsearch must return documents where this field does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an OR(Should query) with the two queries(keyword and field does not exist) for elasticsearch to return documents that either match the keyword on the field or do not have the field at all.

I don't know the keyword match query you are using so I used a term query. Please try this out

```
GET _search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "xyz": {
                  "value": "VALUE"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "xyz"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```